# How does one integrate SignalR .NET Framework

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, signalr

I'm currently working on a not-so-old project which used ReactJS-Redux Toolkit Client and ASP.NET Framework 4.7.2.
The problem is I cannot find any helpful articles on how to implement SignalR .NET Framework to React-Redux, only articles for SignalR .NET CORE. My goal is only to react client receive server messages from SignalR Hub.

Could someone give an example of how to achieve this? (client-side)

Comment: What is the issue, what have you tried? The documentation on the npm package gives you a pretty good starting point 

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/signalr

Comment: @microsoft/signalr is for SignalR Core only. But I successfully achieved my goal by using signalR jquery. Somehow it's beyond my imagination that jquery can be used in ReactJS and leave that aside. Thank you anyway!

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem right now. It is also beyond my imagination that jquery can be used in react. I wish you had posted your solution.